# Ubuntu can not type @

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout

How do I type '@' in Ubuntu?

I am running ubunto in vitual box with a Portuguese keyboard layout. I can't seem to type '@' for emails and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your keyboardsettings according to your keyboardlayout. in this dialog you can test the keys and so you can find the right settings.